# Any way to get a Hibernate SequenceGenerator from spring context?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The app in question is has spring define the LocalSessionFactoryBean for hibernate, and it loads the hibernate configuration from hibernate xml files.  In the hibernate mapping files, the sequence generator class is specified.  Is there any way to specify a spring bean as a sequence generator rather than have hibernate create one based on the mapping configuration?

Comment: I guess the spring-mvc tag is a bit misleading here. You should consider removing it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Short answer: no.</strike>

The problem is, that -even with hibernate4 support in spring 3.1- the spring classes are just 'wrappers' around `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` where `IdentifierGeneratorFactory` is read-only. ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html )

Unless you subclass it and wrap it into spring, I see no way to accomplish this. :(

EDIT:

Misread your question sorry.

You can create your own sequence generator ( https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CustomSequences ) , and if you create a factory for it, that factory can easily be made spring aware, and fully configurable and injectable from spring

Comment: I already have a custom sequence.  I know how to create a factory for it.  What I do not know is how to tell hibernate to use the specific instance of the custom sequence generated from the spring application context.